# How I can add color arrows in a table cell?

Tags: tables, tabularx, arrows, cell

I would like to replace each + and - with green and red arrows, respectively, in my table like table below:

[image]

My table code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 50 & 30.5 & +19.50 \\ 
 10 & 20 & -10.00 \\ 
 33 & 11 & +20.00 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\greenup}{\textcolor{green}{$\uparrow$}}
\newcommand{\reddown}{\textcolor{red}{$\downarrow$}}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 50 & 30.5 & \greenup 19.50 \\ 
 10 & 20 & \reddown  10.00 \\ 
 33 & 11 & \greenup 20.00 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

or with `fontawesome` icons:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\greenup}{\textcolor{green}{\faArrowUp}}
\newcommand{\reddown}{\textcolor{red}{\faArrowDown}}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 50 & 30.5 & \greenup 19.50 \\ 
 10 & 20 & \reddown  10.00 \\ 
 33 & 11 & \greenup 20.00 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```